# Passing data to nested interface

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I am trying to create an object, based on my interface.

### This Works

```js
export interface ServiceDataToDialog {
    id: number,
    service: string,
}
```

```js
constructor(private _dialogRef: MatDialogRef<DialogServiceTabletAddRowComponent>, private _fb: FormBuilder, @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: ServiceDataToDialog) {
  data.id = 1;
  this.mainForm.valueChanges.subscribe(value => {
    data.service = value.service;
```

But I want my object to be nested. So this is what I have tried:

### This doesn't work

```js
export interface ServiceDataToDialog {
    [id: number]: {
      service: string,
    }
}
```

```js
constructor(private _dialogRef: MatDialogRef<DialogServiceTabletAddRowComponent>, private _fb: FormBuilder, @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: ServiceDataToDialog) {
  data.id = 1;
  this.mainForm.valueChanges.subscribe(value => {
    data.id.service = value.service;
```

I get the error:

> TS2339: Property 'id' does not exist on type 'ServiceDataToDialog'.

### This is what I expect:

```json
{
  1: {
    service: "My Service"
  }
}
```

This is another way how I tried it:

```js
export interface ServiceDataToDialog {
    id: {
      service: string,
    }
}
```

```js
constructor(private _dialogRef: MatDialogRef<DialogServiceTabletAddRowComponent>, private _fb: FormBuilder, @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: ServiceDataToDialog) {
    data[1] = data.id;
    this.mainForm.valueChanges.subscribe(value => {
      data.service = value.service;
```

But then I get this error:

> TS7053: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of
> type '1' can't be used to index type 'ServiceDataToDialog'.   Property
> '1' does not exist on type 'ServiceDataToDialog'.

What's wrong with my code?

Comment: The interface of the "not working" code is using an indexer to lookup a string. There is no property defined on the interface named `id`, just like the error states.

Answer (score 0):

Here in your working code ID is string type, in second example you are trying to assign two value to 'string' and 'object' but you can't do this like.

Here you can do this

```
export interface ServiceDataToDialog {
 id: {
  id.string
  service: string,
 }
}
```

and change in your code

```
data.id = 1;
```

To `data.id.id = 1;`

Just learn about javascript object and object destructing

Comment: I don't understand `id.string` in your interface. It is invalid and triggers an error.

Comment: It is a wrong sentax added by mistake.  Change this "Id.string" to "id:string"

Comment: It is a wrong sentax added by mistake.  Change this `id.string` to `id:string`